# Who says that the Eid khotba is a single sermon and who says two and what are their evidences?

Tags: fiqh, reference-request, eid, khutbah

In the last few years I've learnt that there's a difference among scholars about the amount of sermons or sermon parts of the khotba of the Eid's.
Apparently some scholars hold the opinion that Eid prayer has only one single khotba while others say it's likewise to jumu'ah with two khotba parts.

Therefore I'd like to know the different opinions and their evidences if there are any?

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/67942